# Routing around static index.html in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My rails application works okay, but I want there to be a static index.html page in front of it that has a link to the "start" of my application.

I don't know how to tell rails to go wherever it used to go before I put the index.html in.

So, I want "http://localhost:3000/start" to be what "http://localhost:3000" used to be before I put in the index.html.

I tried this in routes.rb:
match 'start' => 'application'

I was thinking that would make /start get handled by application, but "application" was all "Whatchoo talkin bout"

Comment: Do you have an `application_controller`?

Answer (score 2):

@Sam is correct: if there is a public/index.html, it trumps whatever's in your routes.rb file.  Delete it with impunity and you will be happier.

Once you've done that, assuming your static page is in 'views/static/start.html', put this as the last line in config/routes.rb:

```
  root :to => 'static#start'
```

Comment: Documentation on the root route: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

Answer (score 0):

In your `public` folder if you have a filed called `index.html` the application will always go to that first.

Comment: well yeah but surely there's a way to tell rails that my application is at /whatever/ now instead

Answer (score 0):

Sure, put this in your routes.rb:

```
match 'start', controller: 'start', action: 'index'
```

(assuming you have a start_controller with an action 'index')